# goapp deploy: has different path then goapp serve on windows?

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, go

my system:

- golang 1.2.1
- go appengine sdk v1.9.1 windows

using the command line:

- goapp serve

(works)

- goapp deploy

(does not, telling me it can not find my imported packages in my windows GOPATH=...?)

Comment: Does the import { ... } section of your app contain custom package names?

Comment: Not sure about this, but you may need to make sure you've pulled all 3rd party packages with `goapp get` instead of just `go get`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes that is it, can you create answer please

Comment: o wait now it can not find a custom name import { oauth2 "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/oauth2/v2" } the other non custom one was found after goapp get instead of go get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed in go appengine sdk v1.9.3 windows